# AddSupportedUILanguage() bug in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, bug

Around December 2014 there has been an update to the CSOM model for on-premises SharePoint 2013.
The update unfortunately included a bug in AddSupportedUILanguage() function:
[

> Update on 20th of Dec  - Adding additional language to web has
>   unfortunately a bug and it does not work unless site has already one
>   or more additional languages set, which means that this API does not
>   really usable until this bug is fixed. This will be fixed for future
>   releases and to redistributable version of the CSOM package.

][1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/12/15/latest-api-updates-in-client-side-object-model-dec-2014-cu-for-sp2013.aspx)

As stated above, the bug was supposed to be fixed in future releases. I am currently using a release for SPO from 9April 2015, and the bug still persists. Any ideas as to where it has been fixed (maybe I have some wrong release) or when it is going to be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before running the `ClientContext.Web.AddSupportedUILanguage()`,

set:   `ClientContext.Web.IsMultilingual = true;`